# Practice problem on ACTEX book.

Tags: probability, statistics

A probability distribution of the claim sizes for an auto insurance policy is given in the table below:

```
Claim size Probability 
20           0.15 
30           0.10 
40           0.05
50           0.20 
60           0.10 
70           0.10 
80           0.30
```

What percentage of the claims are within one standard deviation of the claim size mode?

I know how to get one standard deviation of mean claim size but need help with claim side mode. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The mode is the value that appears most often in the set of data. In this case, it would be 30. Do you some difficulties with this?

Comment: What do you think the standard deviation is here? The mode?

Comment: @MattiP. - I do not see $30$ as the mode here

Comment: Ah, it was a typo. I meant $80$ of course.